# example usage of xt::where for xtensor C++

Tags: numpy, c++14, xtensor

I am new to the xtensor. I am wondering how one would use the output from xt::where. In python, for example assuming imap is an nd array,
np.where(imap>=4) returns two arrays with indices and can be assigned directly using the = operator. Please let me know how to use it in the xtensor C++ context. Any small example would be a great help.

Thanks.

Comment: What you're describing is really `np.nonzero(imap >= 4)`, which `np.where(one_arg)` is an unfortunate shorthand for.

Answer (score 5):

returns xt::xarray of input type.

```
xt::xarray<int> res = xt::where(b, a1, a2);
```

`b` is a true then elements of array `a1` are returned, if `b` is false elements of `a2` are returned.

The below example is copied from documentation (search for `xt::where`)
http://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operator.html

b's first element is `false` - so get it from `a2` -- 11

b's second element is `true` - so get it from `a1` -- 2

b's third element is `true`  - so get it from `a1` -- 3

b's fourth element is `false` - so get it from `a2` -- 14

```
xt::xarray<bool> b = { false, true, true, false };
xt::xarray<int> a1 = { 1,   2,  3,  4 };
xt::xarray<int> a2 = { 11, 12, 13, 14 };

xt::xarray<int> res = xt::where(b, a1, a2);
// => res = { 11, 2, 3, 14 }
```